# response class with generic <T>

Tags: c#, generics

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I can't find it and I'm not exactly sure what to search on.

I've got a generic response class like this:

```
 public class ResponseModel<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public Exception Ex { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to do something like the code below so that I can simply pass the errors up the stack by doing a `return retVal.Set<T>(responseModelObject);`

```
    public ResponseModel<T> Set<T>(ResponseModel<T> rm)
    {
        Ex = rm.Ex;
        Message = rm.Message;
        return this;
    }
```

This works fine if the `T` class is identical between `retVal` and `responseModelObject`, but won't compile if they don't match.

Is there a way to do this or am I just sol?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at existing examples on how to solve this kind of problem, since a response/result object is a fairly well know pattern, for example: https://github.com/altmann/FluentResults

Comment: Thanks. I will read up on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may create an interface

```csharp
public interface IResponseModel
{
    Exception Ex { get; set; }
    string Message { get; set; }
    bool Success { get; set; }
}

public class ResponseModel<T> : IResponseModel
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
    public Exception Ex { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

Then the method will look like

```csharp
public ResponseModel<T> Set(IResponseModel rm)
{
    Ex = rm.Ex;
    Message = rm.Message;
    return this;
}
```

Also interface will allow you to create collections of `IResponseModel` which may conrain generics of different types. It maybe also useful with `async` operations like `Task<IResponseModel>`, etc.

Comment: Thanks.  This would probably work too but I went with Dmitry's suggestion first, and it works.  Much appreciated though.

Comment: Actually I changed my code to use your answer. It's better. Thanks.  Now I don't have to pass in the class of the incoming object.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to declare method as:

```
public ResponseModel<T> Set<TOther>(ResponseModel<TOther> rm)
{
    Ex = rm.Ex;
    Message = rm.Message;
    return this;
}
```

Sample usage:

```
ResponseModel<int> a = new ResponseModel<int>();
ResponseModel<string> b = new ResponseModel<string>();
b.Set(a); // It compiles
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this working ?

```java
public ResponseModel<T,S> Set<S>(ResponseModel<T> rm)
{
    Ex = rm.Ex;
    Message = rm.Message;
    return this;
}
```

Comment: No, but it was a good try.  I also tried ResponseModel<T> Set<S>(responsemodel<T> rm) and also ResponseModel<T> Set<T>(ResponseModel<S>) with no luck.  The second one worked except I couldn't do a "return this" at the end.